# Why array loops works in Python to remove duplicated entries, but JS don't?

Tags: javascript, python, arrays

I'm new in programming and I already have a little bit of background in Python.
At the moment, I'm studying Javascript and I was doing an exercise that should remove duplicate entries in an array.
I don't understand why the logic bellow doesn't work in JS, but works in Python. Can someone explain to me?

Javascript:

```
let array = [3, 3, 3, 4, 5];
let noRepetition = [];

for (let i of array) {
    if (!(i in noRepetition)) {
        noRepetition.push(i)
    }
}

console.log('Before ', array);
console.log('After ', noRepetition);
```

Output:

```
Before  [ 3, 3, 3, 4, 5 ]
After  [ 3, 3, 3, 4, 5 ]
```

Python:

```
array = [3, 3, 3, 4, 5]
noRepetition = []

for i in array:
    if not i in noRepetition:
        noRepetition.append(i)

print(f'Before {array}')
print(f'After {noRepetition}')
```

Output:

```
Before [3, 3, 3, 4, 5]
After [3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: You're misinterpreting how `in` works in JS (see the [manual](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in)). Use `!noRepetition.includes(i)` or `noRepetition.indexOf(i) != -1` or ... instead

Comment: thanks, helps a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the `in` operator in javascript is not working as in python and checks keys (for an array, indexes).

```
> "a" in ["a", "b"]
false
> 1 in ["a", "b"]
true
> 2 in ["a", "b"]
false
```

You can use [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes):

```
> ["a", "b"].includes("a")
true
```

And this should work as you expect.

You should also check libraries like lodash which provide a [function for this](https://lodash.com/docs#uniq).

Also you might want to consider using [`Set`s](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) if you want your data structure to be duplicate-free:

```
Array.from(new Set([2, 1, 3, 1]))
[ 2, 1, 3 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript: `in` operator parameters description:
**A string or symbol representing a property name or array index (non-symbols will be coerced to strings).**

which mean:

```js
// Arrays
let trees = ['redwood', 'bay', 'cedar', 'oak', 'maple']
0 in trees        // returns true
3 in trees        // returns true
6 in trees        // returns false
'bay' in trees    // returns false (you must specify the index number, not the value at that index)
'length' in trees // returns true (length is an Array property)
Symbol.iterator in trees // returns true (arrays are iterable, works only in ES2015+)

// Predefined objects
'PI' in Math          // returns true

// Custom objects
let mycar = {make: 'Honda', model: 'Accord', year: 1998}
'make' in mycar  // returns true
'model' in mycar // returns true
```

[in operator - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in)